# How do I insert cells by dates?

Tags: google-sheets

[image]

I want to extract company name and its contract price and cost only from 2-14jan 2022? How can i do that?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sample setup with raw data in Columns A-E

Cells H1, H2 has the date inputs which you can manipulate accordingly.

formula:

```
=FILTER(C:E,B:B>=H1,B:B<=H2)
```

alternate formula:

```
=QUERY(A2:E,"SELECT C,D,E WHERE B>=DATE '"&TEXT(H1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' AND B<=DATE '"&TEXT(H2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' ")
```

**NOTE**: the above formula(s) are bound to throw error incase the date in your second column is not a [proper date format](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9061381?hl=en) and rather a text date

[image]